# Parse floating point numbers, and single periods/dots in ANTLR 3

Tags: java, antlr, cobol

How to parse the floating point numbers, and a single periods/dots in ANTLR 3?

Here is the details of my problem...

```
    grammar AntlrCobolParser;

options {
   k=8;
   output=AST;
   language=Java;
}

@header {

package com;
}

@lexer::header {
package com;
}


untilStmt
: 'UNTIL' condition (stopword | DOT)
{
  System.out.println("UNTIL condition: " + $condition.text);
}
;

fragment
condition : ( condWord )+
;

fragment 
condWord : (IDENTIFIER | NUMERIC | HEXNUMBER | STRING)
;


STRING
: '"' (~('"') | ('"') ('"') )* '"'  | '\'' (~('\'') | ('\'') ('\'') )* '\''
;


WS  
: ( BL | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C' | ',' |  ';' )+
{
  { $channel = HIDDEN; }
}
;

fragment BL : ( ' ' | '\t' ) ;

stopword : word = ( 'DELETE' 'OPEN' | 'REWRITE' | 'STOP' | 'WRITE' | 'ALTER'
  | 'IF' | 'ELSEIF' | 'THEN' | 'ELSE' | 'ENDIF' | 'NEXT' | 'WHEN'
  | 'ENDEVALUATE' | 'ENDPERFORM' | 'ENDSTART' | 'ENDCALL' | 'EXIT')
{
  input.rewind();
}
;

IDENTIFIER
: id=ID1 | id=ID2
;

fragment ID1
: ('0'..'9')+ ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'-'|'_'|':') ('0'..'9'|':'|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'-'|'_')*
;

fragment ID2
: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|':'|'@') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|':'|'-'|'_')*
;

NUMERIC 
: ('+'|'-')? (('0'..'9')+ (('.') ('0'..'9')+)? | ( ('.') ('0'..'9')+ ) )
;

HEXNUMBER
: ('h' | 'H' | 'x' | 'X') ( (QUOTECHAR ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+ QUOTECHAR) | (APOSTROPHE ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+ APOSTROPHE) ) ;

fragment QUOTECHAR : '"' ;                         
fragment APOSTROPHE: '\'' ;

DOT 
: '.'
;
```

This parser grammar extracts all **UNTIL** conditions correctly but gives incorrect result on condition ends-with DOT e.g.

```
3700A-FIND-ERRORS.
          MOVE PL-0048-KEY-APPL-CODE-M     TO TBLBKT  (01).
          MOVE PL-0048-KEY-APPL-NBR-M      TO TBLBKT  (02).
          MOVE PL-0048-KEY-SUB-ACCT-M      TO TBLBKT  (03).

          MOVE '0048-KEY-APPL-CODE      '  TO TBLDESC (01).
          MOVE '0048-KEY-APPL-NBR       '  TO TBLDESC (02).
          MOVE '0048-KEY-SUB-ACCT       '  TO TBLDESC (03).

          MOVE 3     TO MAX-ERRORS-CNT.
          PERFORM 6000-BUILD-ERRORS
             THRU 6000-BUILD-ERRORS-EXIT
           VARYING SUB FROM 1 BY 1
             UNTIL SUB GREATER THAN 3.
   3700A-FIND-ERRORS-EXIT.
       EXIT.
```

In the above example it gives **SUB GREATER THAN 3 3700A-FIND-ERRORS-EXIT** as a UNTIL condition, which is incorrect. I am trying to parse the Mainframe COBOL source.

Please tell what is incorrect in my assumptions?

Thanks in advance!
Kishore

Comment: Please include examples of input sequences and the *exact* sequence of tokens that you expect from the input. For example, exactly what token or tokens do you want to see produced by the input `3.`? What about `3`? What about `3.0`? What about `.0`? What about `+3.`? etc...

Comment: plz see the updated text.

Comment: Yes, I shall provide here.

Comment: Actually the contents provided above are the parts of my COBOL project. What else required to elaborate my problem?

Comment: What is the intended use of you analysis of the COBOL programs? Unless you stick to that, you'll end up having to mimic the compiler (which will be silly and non-trivial) or make use of the compiler. So, what is the intended use...?

Comment: Just to extract the conditions from a COBOL program i.e. save conditions into Database.

Comment: I like "just". Do you mean for IF, EVALUATE, PERFORM ... UNTIL ..., PERFORM ... TIMES, SEARCH ... UNTIL, and every other verb which has a "scope-delimiter" (END-...)? What information are you going to store in your database? Just "this condition is used somewhere in this program" or what?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but you may be in way in over your head here. COBOL is a difficult language to
write a good parser for. Unless you have a very strong grasp of parsing techniques and
COBOL language syntax, you are in for a whole lot of hurt here.

From what I gather you are trying to write an island parser (see [island parsers](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Island+Grammars+Under+Parser+Control))
where the only things of interest are conditional expressions. At a minimum I think you
would have to write a parser to first isolate the `PROCEDURE DIVISION` and then decompose it into 
`SECTION/PARAGRAPH/SENTENCE/STATEMENT` structure.
Once a `STATEMENT` has been extracted you can then island parse only those statements that potentially contain conditional expressions.

Why do you need this much detail to parse conditional expressions from statements? Your code example may be used to illustrate the point. 
Your current parser
sees the `UNTIL` phrase as:

```
           UNTIL SUB GREATER THAN 3.
```

and it is intrepreting the `3.` as a floating point constant. This is not a floating point constant. In the context of the larger code fragment:

```
        PERFORM 6000-BUILD-ERRORS
           THRU 6000-BUILD-ERRORS-EXIT
         VARYING SUB FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL SUB GREATER THAN 3.
 3700A-FIND-ERRORS-EXIT.
     EXIT.
```

the only possible intrepretation of the period is that of a statement terminator, which also happens to be a paragraph terminator (every paragraph
must be terminated by a period - next line of code is a new paragraph header so the previous period must be a paragraph terminator).

I am sure with a little imagination you can solve this specific problem using some ad-hoc parsing rule. But this is not the point of my response. My point is that without fully understanding the
syntax of COBOL you will never be able to build a robust parser.

As an illustration of the type of problems you are likely to run into, consider the following conditional statement:

```
    IF A > B AND C
```

The exact meaning of this conditional cannot be determined until you know what `C` represents. If `C` is a simple variable then the meaning
is:

```
    IF (A > B) AND (A > C)
```

However, if `C` is an 88 level name such as this:

```
    01 WS-X     PIC X.
       88 C     VALUE 'A' THRU 'D'.
```

The meaning becomes

```
    IF (A > B) AND (WS-X = 'A' OR
                    WS-X = 'B' OR
                    WS-X = 'C' OR
                    WS-X = 'D')
```

As you can see these are quite different. Conditional expressions such as illustrated above require sophisticated parsing techniques
to resolve.

Comment: I've already been binning comments on this, as there were so many it was suggesting a chat room instead. Now I can abandon my draft answer as well :-) Conditions *could* be extracted just as a lump of text, but without clarity from @Kishore about what the use of the information will be, no way to know if that is useful. I always use the compile listing, with the verbs, the map, the indenting done by the compiler for conditions, normalisation of data-name numbers and definitions. Have to go looking for OCCURS at times, but not too bad.

Comment: Thx @NealB. In my application I am using Island-Grammar approach as you explained. All things are working fine without failure of parser. But the issue is the parse is not able to distinguish between NUMERIC and DOT (comes just after the pure integer).

Answer (score 1):

You may well be able to do this with your definition of DOT. If the column 72 requirement is problematic, bear in mind that columns 73-80 can be entirely blank if you like, so you could clear column 73 and treat your data as columns 8-73.

If you can't define your DOT that way...

A simple way to deal with the example problem in you question is to pre-process the `PROCEDURE DIVISION` code. Identify all ". ", remove the "." and create a new line with the "." in column 12. Identify all "." in column 72, remove that "." also and again create a new line with the "." in column 12. You must ignore alphanumeric-literals whilst doing this (text starting with " until next ", or ' until next ').

This will not affect the program in any way (you can take an example and compile it, the results will be identical, byte-for-byte of the object (excluding compile date/time) to the original program). Even if there are already lines just containing "." it would not hurt to change them, or you could leave those as-is. No difference.

If you are just extracting the text of conditions, this will help. If you are trying to parse the conditions fully, you have the problems NealB has pointed out.

Bear in mind that there are many places where conditions can exist. Everything which has an END- in can contain a condition. Perhaps `AT END` in a `READ` is not significant, but `ON SIZE ERROR`, where it can exist, is, for instance.

In your example, the condition in isolation, without the information in the `VARYING`, loses a lot of context. You will have similar problems in trying to deal with other conditions in isolation.

I'm really not sure what you expect to get out of this. In the example, you have a condition which is just looking at the loop-control variable. You could have a similar-looking condition which was not looking at a loop-control variable, and just from looking at the condition you would not be able to tell them apart with certainty. You should be able to extract the text which makes up the condition, but it may not be what is required for the final process.

I'd suggest doing a couple of programs manually/semi-manually and working that data all the way down the line. If everything goes fine, no problem. If you need to make changes, they may negate work done now to get what you have already to a state where you think it is working but there requirement you've been given is deficient.

Comment: Thx @Bill. Your solution is considerable but it may result into incorrect line number (which is required to store with condition) also the processing becomes slow on very large program e.g. 25000 lines

Comment: @Kishore Line-number need not be a problem. You just use the original line-number. I think you should experiment before saying things like "it'll be slow for 25,000" because if what you are using is slow, using something else should be fast. 25,000 lines is not a lot of data for a program. Again, please, detail of what your requirement.

Comment: My requirements are to extract all conditions of IF, EVALUATE-WHEN, UNTIL etc statements along-with correct line numbers and save into database for a analysis tool to evaluate further.